# Unit testing http session cookies python3

Tags: unit-testing, session, cookies, python-3.x

I'm unittesting a WSGI application I'm writing in Python 3.2
I've been looking for a way to pass a session cookie from one request to the next.

The self.cli is a http.client.HTTPConnection

The cookie is a http.cookies.SimpleCookie

```
def testLogonCookie(self):
    self.cli.connect()
    self.cli.request("POST", '/login', b'user=GUI&pass=Junkie')
    res = self.cli.getresponse()
    heads = res.getheader('Set-Cookie')
    print(heads)
    txt = str(res.readall())
    self.assertGreater(txt.find('Lorum ipsum'), -1, 'testLogin')
    head = {"HTTP_COOKIE": heads}
    print(head)

    ####Exception here
    self.cli.request('GET', '/loggedon', head) 

    res = self.cli.getresponse()
    txt = str(res.readall())
    print(txt)
    self.assertGreater(txt.find('user=GUI_Junkie'), -1, 'testLogonCookie')
```

The first print trace is SID=0422f293-58e4-45a9-ab07-a4881c7b98d0; expires=2014-03-29 17:39:55.868140

The second is {'HTTP_COOKIE': 'SID=0422f293-58e4-45a9-ab07-a4881c7b98d0; expires=2014-03-29 17:39:55.868140'}

The exception I get is `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

I suspect I have to parse the `getheader` and put it in a dict, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to go about it. In the end, I just want to push the cookie from one request into the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request call is erroneous. The third argument is the body of the request.         `request('GET', '/loggedon', headers=head)`

```
def testLogonCookie(self):
    self.cli.connect()
    self.cli.request("POST", '/login', b'user=GUI&pass=Junkie')
    res = self.cli.getresponse()
    heads = res.getheader('Set-Cookie')
    txt = str(res.readall())
    self.assertGreater(txt.find('Lorum ipsum'), -1, 'testLogin')
    head = {'Cookie': heads}
    self.cli.request('GET', '/loggedon', headers=head)
    res = self.cli.getresponse()
    txt = str(res.readall())
    self.assertGreater(txt.find('user=GUI_Junkie'), -1, 'testLogonCookie')
```